# How to see password as we type it

Tags: debian, terminal, login, password, root

In debian wheezy terminal I type

```
su -
```

It ask for password, which I type but it doesn't show anything as

```
Password:
```

I want to it to show at least some asterisks as the placeholder for the password characters as follow:

```
Password: ************
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a way to do it with "sudo" but it does not work with su...
But if you want to display "*" with sudo, you need to add this line in "/etc/sudoers" file :

```
Defaults pwfeedback
```

Comment: That did not work for me
i did `visudo`

then inserted `Defaults pwfeedback` **which failed** then i inserted `Defaults pwfeedback="*"` **which also failed**.

Any idea ...

Comment: Did you tried with "su" or "sudo" ?

Comment: **BOTH**

`sudo apt-get install vlc` -- FAILED

`su -` as said by you FAILED too

Comment: That's weird, it's working for me with sudo, I added the line at the end of my sudoers file. You can also add it elsewhere. For example, after env_reset -> "Defaults   env_reset, pwfeedback".

Comment: i added it after `Defaults secure_path=""`, however thank you very much for your sincere efforts.

Comment: Are you sure that the sudoers file has been modified and not copied in sudoers.tmp for example ? What is your sudo version ? (you can get it using : $ sudo -V). Because pwfeedback is a feature of the version 1.8.6p3

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10245/discussion-between-nishan-and-junior-d)

Comment: yes this may a cause `1.8.5p2`. Need an update ???

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there something that can be done about this?

No, unfortunately. It's **an inconsistency in the interface** (*visual feedback in the GUI, no visual feedback in the terminal*), and inconsistencies confuse new users.

I started a [thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=214393) about this in the Ubuntu Forums called Feedback on entering password in the terminal? I even filed a [bug report on the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shadow/+bug/52914), but the developers have rejected it.

### So, you've just got to get used to it.

from http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/passwordinterminal

Comment: It is a security feature and intentional. Giving away the amount of characters the password consists off is already a valuable information for anyone trying to guess it.

Comment: If you really want to implement that, look at the line discipline implementation in the kernel; it won't be hard to hack eg an `ECHO_STAR` termios `c_lflag` in, that could be then easily used by any program  (I won't comment whether this is a good idea or not). Otherwise, I don't see how playing the UX pundit is helping anyone -- you cannot expect every program that has to get a password from the user to do its own idiosyncratic workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `stty echo </dev/pts/N` from another window, where `/dev/pts/N` is the terminal you're running `su` in (get its name with `tty` before running `su`).

You can probably bind a key to that in your terminal emulator -- I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.