# How to make typing passwords visible?

Tags: linux, terminal, sudo, password, su

When `sudo`ing in terminal a user has to type password to gain root privileges. While typing what I am typing is not visible at all. I have mental disabilities so I often forget which character I was on while typing a 10-letter password, forcing me to start over since there is no indicator of how many and what letters I have typed so far. Is there a modification that makes the process visible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see password as we type it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87607/how-to-see-password-as-we-type-it)

Comment: Is it possible in your workflow to type your password in another window (like an editor where you can see it) and copy-and-paste it into the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [Ubuntu Users: How to Asterisks When Typing Your Password in a Terminal](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/make-sudo-password-visible-terminal) is what you're looking for?

The asterisks will indicate how many characters you have entered so far.

1. Open a new Terminal window (Ctrl + Alt + T) and enter the following command:

   ```
   sudo visudo
   ```
2. Use your keyboard navigation keys (or mouse scroll wheel) to move to the line that reads:

   ```
   Defaults env_reset
   ```
3. Move the square box to the end of this line and add the following text so that it reads:

   ```
   Defaults env_reset,pwfeedback
   ```

Save the file. All done.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please don't post links as answers: first, if the link changes or breaks, the answer becomes useless and second, we are trying to collect answers _here_, not send people somewhere else to find it. Can you please edit your answer and explain what the solution you linked to suggests?